# Subquery with a JSON property

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a working query which extracts Events of type `'Searched for Flights'` from the following table:

```
SELECT "public"."events"."id" AS "id", "public"."events"."event" AS "event", "public"."events"."created_at" AS "created_at", "public"."events"."insert_id" AS "insert_id", "public"."events"."properties" AS "properties", "public"."events"."user_id" AS "user_id"
FROM "public"."events"
WHERE "public"."events"."event" = 'Searched for Flights'
LIMIT 1048576
```

[image: Table]

How to add a subquery that filters the event `'Searched for Flights'` by property `type = "return"`?

Comment: which rdms are you actually using?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres you can use the `->>` operator to extract the value for a key from a `json` column:

```
SELECT evt.id, 
       evt.event, 
       evt.created_at, 
       evt.insert_id, 
       evt.properties, 
       evt.user_id
FROM public.events evt
WHERE evt.event = 'Searched for Flights'
  AND evt.properties ->> 'type' = 'return'
LIMIT 1048576
```